# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient logout

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a console application that uses [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts), but it only prompts the login once. After logging in I cant find out how to logout.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete the key(s) from regedit.

In the end of your code, you can add the step to **delete the subkey(s)** under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp
```

Then no credential information will be cached after closing the app.